# Change Case of last searched pattern

Tags: evil, search, replace

Is there a fast way of changing the case of the last searched pattern?

Inside `Evil` mode, I press `#` key to quickly search for keywords at point. And I want to change the case of all occurences of that keyword.

Comment: @phils I was looking for something even quicker. I've added a new answer. Please see that. And thanks for bumping the post, in case you did it :)

Comment: I think it was a convenient automated bump.  I've added my suggestion as an answer for non-Evil users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer using Evil mode. After issuing the search using `#` key in Evil mode, just issue this substitution command:

```
:%s//\U&/g
```

Here, `%s` is for substitution, `//` means that it will use the last searched pattern, `/\U&/` means it will upper-case (`\U`) the complete match (`&`), and `g` is for global, i.e. substitute all the matches.

Answer (score 1):

For a vanilla Emacs approach, you might use:

- <kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>M-c</kbd> to initiate a case-sensitive search (assuming that you have `isearch-case-fold-search` enabled by default).
- <kbd>C-w</kbd> to search/match the word at point (or whatever you need to do to isearch the thing you're looking at/for).
- <kbd>M-%</kbd> to enter the case-sensitive replacement for all matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `q ?`: this will open a small buffer with your last searches using `#` (and `?`) and then you can edit in-place the last command used and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute that search

Comment: I think you misunderstood: I don't think the OP wanted to search again for the pattern with case chagned, but to change the case of the ocurrences of the pattern in the buffer. (Maybe... I'm not really sure what OP wants.)

Comment: Come to think of it, I also understood the same as you, @Omar, but I forgot to add "there is no such thing, but the closest is..." at the beginning. I'll try to add a command to do it automatically